# Need to add a string to the end of first names in an array using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following array.

```
var gillFamily = [
  { name: 'john', age: 20 }, 
  { name: 'richard', age: 27 }, 
  { name: 'debbie', age: 55 }, 
  { name: 'dan', age: 25 }, 
  { name: 'robin', age: 60 }
];
```

I need to print the names with the lastname "Gill" added to them using lodash.

I've tried this which was the closest I got:

```
_.map(gillFamily, "name") + " Gill";
```

but that only adds Gill to the last name in the array.

How do I add the `name` to all items in the array?

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```
_.map(gillFamily, (el) => el.name + " Gill");
```

In case that the environment doesn't support ES6:

```
_.map(gillFamily, function(el) { 
   return el.name + " Gill" 
});
```

You could also use `Array.prototype.map` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `name` property inside the Object and then add the `Gill` string to that name.

```js
var gillFamily = [  {name: 'john', age: 20},
      {name: 'richard', age: 27},
      {name: 'debbie', age: 55}, 
      {name: 'dan', age :25}, 
      {name: 'robin', age : 60}];

var gillFamilyWithLastNameAdded = _.map(gillFamily, person => person.name + " Gill");
console.log(gillFamilyWithLastNameAdded);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Using the map function you can map each element with the last name appended to using the following.</strike> Using `_.each()`, you can loop over the array of objects and update the property/properties desired. This probably may not be the best/most efficient technique but it's the best I could find by just reading the docs.

*Note: This will overwrite the original object.*

*Disclaimer: I'm not an active lodash user.*

```js
// Setup example data
var gillFamily = [{
  name: 'john',
  age: 20
}, {
  name: 'richard',
  age: 27
}, {
  name: 'debbie',
  age: 55
}, {
  name: 'dan',
  age: 25
}, {
  name: 'robin',
  age: 60
}];

// Display the initial values
document.getElementById("start").innerText = JSON.stringify(gillFamily);

// Append family name on the current family member's name
var gillFamilyWithLastNames = _.each(gillFamily, function(el) {
  // Append 'Gill' to the end of the existing name
  el.name += ' Gill';
});

// Show the results
document.getElementById("end").innerText = JSON.stringify(gillFamilyWithLastNames);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<p>Starting Data</p>
<pre id="start"></pre>
<p>Ending Data</p>
<pre id="end"></pre>
```